# how do i remove %20 extra keyword url error in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

how do i remove %20 extra keyword url error in .htaccess ?

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule (.*)_hello_(.*)_lan_(.*)_html.html$ view_html.php?q=$1&sq=$2&lang=$3 [B,L]
RewriteRule (.*)_hello_(.*)_lan_(.*)_plain.html$ view_plain.php?q=$1&sq=$2&lang=$3 [B,L]
```

that extra %20 url got error..

http://example.com/Higher%20education_wikipedia_EDUCATIONS_lan_en_html.html

Comment: What error? `%20` is the URL representation of a space. As long as you use spaces in the URL you will have `%20`in there.

Comment: And the example URL does not match the rules you've posted? Is `_hello_` supposed to represent `_wikipedia_`??